# Creating a dynamic database

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql server connected to Access, and I want to do a form, to fill the table.

My question is how to do it. I need to select the data from a listbox, that's okay this is already done. And I need that the listbox only shows the options that have more than 1 in "stock". Should I do a query to count how many are left and apply that query as data source? If yes, how can I do it? Or any other ideas?